# How are suggested edit results displayed to low rep users?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

When suggested edits were introduced, I had more rep than required to edit on my own.

Since I'm now approving and rejecting suggested edits, I'd like to know how approval and rejection are presented to the users that suggest them.

I can see how the suggested edits form looks like when logging out. But I don't want to suggest edits just to see the results, and I'm not sure if anonymous user/Community suggested edits responses appear identical to regular, lower-rep users'.

Are they in the global inbox? In the users profile, and if so, where? *Responses*? *Activity*?

Some screenshots with a general description would be nice.

Comment: `[feature-request]` on changing this is here: [Reject reasons for suggested edits should be displayed as a notification for the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/reject-reasons-for-suggested-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-for-the)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't actively "pushed" to your inbox. The only way to find out if an edit suggestion was accepted or rejected is to:

- Check your reputation
- Check your activity

This applies to both approved and rejected edits. You will *not* be notified. At least I didn't get a notification for [this](https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/7364).

---

#### Looking at your reputation

For example, if your reputation changed by +2, obviously, your edit was accepted:

[image]

But that doesn't show you anything about rejected edits.

#### Looking under *Activity*

You can also go to your *Profile » Activity » Suggestions*. Here you'll find all your suggested edits. Still, this page doesn't list whether an edit was approved or rejected.

[image]

#### Looking at the individual edits

You have to click the "suggested edit" link to actually find out:

[image]

Further scrolling down, you can see more about your recent editor statistics:

[image]

Comment: Can't talk about whether there's any other procedure for `rejected` edits, as I've never had one. I would doubt there is a difference though. Needless to say I think that this procedure could be way more verbose for the user suggesting edits.

Comment: The rejected edits would be most interesting, as I wonder exactly how pointless giving good reasons for rejection is. That approval as the "default" doesn't generate any notification is understandable.

Comment: Do you think that would make a nice feature request?

Comment: Absolutely. At least rejection messages should be made a notification bar like the "You have 1 new response … " message. Otherwise what's the point? You'll never be able to teach users otherwise. I might consider looking on MSO if there's something similar already and post it there later on, unless you want to post it here?

Comment: Exactly what I feared. Please go ahead on MSO.